play a randomly generated array of audio files, one by one, in javascript
I'm on the first steps of trying to create a simon game using vanilla javascript.
I am able to generate a randomized array of colors, which then I'm hoping to pass to a playSequentially function that will play the audio files related to each color, one by one.
However, my playSequentially function is not working as expected. It often will not play a sound if that sound has already been played. However, this behavior doesn't seem predictable. For example, given this array ['purple', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'purple', 'red'], purple will be played twice but red will only be played once. I've been reading documentation on MDN - looking into currentTime, or reseting the ended attribute. I've ask chatGPT. But to no avail. Is there a way to fix this code, or am I just going about this the wrong way entirely? Thank you


let greenBtn = document.getElementById("green-button");
let redBtn = document.getElementById("red-button");
let blueBtn = document.getElementById("blue-button");
let purpleBtn = document.getElementById("purple-button");
let greenAudio = document.getElementById("green-audio");
let redAudio = document.getElementById("red-audio");
let blueAudio = document.getElementById("blue-audio");
let purpleAudio = document.getElementById("purple-audio");
let playback = document.getElementById("play");
greenBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  greenAudio.play();
})
redBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  redAudio.play();
})
blueBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  blueAudio.play();
})
purpleBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  purpleAudio.play();
})
let audioArray = [greenAudio, blueAudio, redAudio, purpleAudio];
function playAudio(audio) {
  audio.play();
}
function getAudioFromColor(color) {
  switch (color) {
    case "green":
      return greenAudio;
    case "blue":
      return blueAudio;
    case "red":
      return redAudio;
    case "purple":
      return purpleAudio;
  }
}
//create random array of colors of length n
function getRandomColorArray(n) {
  let randomColorArray = []
  let colors = ["green", "blue", "red", "purple"];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < n) {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    console.log(index)
    randomColorArray.push(colors[index]);
    i++;
  }
  return randomColorArray;
}
function playSequentially(audioColorArray) {
  let delay = 500;
  let currentAudio = getAudioFromColor(audioColorArray[0]);
  currentAudio.play();
  for (let i = 0; i < audioColorArray.length - 1; i++) {
    delay += 500;
    currentAudio = getAudioFromColor(audioColorArray[i]);
    currentAudio.onended = setTimeout(() => {
      getAudioFromColor(audioColorArray[i + 1]).play();
    }, delay);
  }
}
playback.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // let randomColorArray = getRandomColorArray(5);
  let randomColorArray = ['purple', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'purple', 'red']
  console.log(randomColorArray)
  playSequentially(randomColorArray);
});
div {
  margin: 10px;
  /* padding: 10px; */
}
.game-btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red
}
.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
.green:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.blue:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.red:hover {
  background-color: lightcoral
}
.purple:hover {
  background-color: plum;
}
#play {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Document</title>
<div class="container" style="max-width: 75%;">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class=" btn" id="play"> Playback</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="game-btn green btn" id="green-button"></div>
    <audio id="green-audio" src="./sounds/539252-Kalimba-INTIMATE-D5-01.wav"></audio>
    <div class="game-btn blue btn" id="blue-button"></div>
    <audio id="blue-audio" src="./sounds/539256-Kalimba-INTIMATE-E6-01.wav"></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="game-btn red btn" id="red-button"></div>
    <audio id="red-audio" src="./sounds/539257-Kalimba-INTIMATE-F4-01.wav"></audio>
    <div class="game-btn purple btn" id="purple-button"></div>
    <audio id="purple-audio" src="./sounds/539258-Kalimba-INTIMATE-F5-01.wav"></audio>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="./assignment22.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




I'd suggest opening your browser console with F12 and have a look at errors reported there. To me, let i = 0; i < audioColorArray.length - 1; looks like an issue. Here you basically say "If i is smaller than the array length minus 1, loop". So if you have an array with 3 items, then it will only loop on 0 and 1, as 2 is smaller than the array length, but not smaller than the array length minus 1.

currentAudio.onended needs to be a function.  Try currentAudio.onended = () => setTimeout( … );

I also suggest you look up event delegation so you do not need to have a click on every button

@mplungjan oh cool - i will check it out!

setTimeout is not a great way when you have onended.
Also you have closure issues.
You will need to trim the notes if you do not want to have a delay while the note starts and ebbs out.

Here is one way of doing it
const playSequentially = (audioColorArray) => {
  let index = 0; // Start from the first color
  const playNextAudio = () => {
    if (index < audioColorArray.length) {
      const audioElement = getAudioFromColor(audioColorArray[index]);
      audioElement.currentTime = 0; // Reset the audio time
      audioElement.play(); 
      audioElement.onended = () => {
        index++; // Move to the next index
        playNextAudio(); // Recursively call to play the next audio
      };
    }
  }
  playNextAudio(); // Start 
};
const colorArray = ['purple', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'purple', 'red'];

playback.addEventListener("click", () => {
  colorArray.sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random());
  console.log(colorArray)
  playSequentially(colorArray);
});

Here is how to delegate and shorten the script a lot
This replaces the first 21 lines of your script
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('button.game-btn'); // did we click inside a game button?
  if (!tgt) return; // no, leave
  const audioElement = document.getElementYyId(tgt.id.replace('button','audio');
  audioElement.currentTime = 0;
  audioElement.play();
});


thank you for the quick response. this solution does seem to work, however it plays the audio files very slowly. Perhaps because it is recursive? I had tried a few things with setTimeout to get the audios to play faster, but to no avail. For example, using                 setTimeout(playNext, delay), although you mentioned it's not good to user with onended. Do you know how to add the functionality to make the files play with a shorter delay between them?

The MP3s are 2 seconds and have a long tail: https://imgur.com/a/8PpTR4Y so onended will trigger after that tail

ok - so I guess I'm off to try to edit the mp3s! thanks for your help

YW. Too bad we cannot use the notes directly from their site

@LauraMansfield I wrote you some event-delegation

thank you! I see, so this only adds the event listener to the button once it has been clicked, correct?

No, it adds the event listener to the CONTAINER and THAT listens to any click inside it and our IF decides if it was a button or not
